# How to check File Read Permission?

Tags: c#-4.0, file-permissions, file-access

I have searched for file permission examples but they didn't work. Examples that I tried:

**Example 1:**

```
try
{
   FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
   f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
   f.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, fullpath);
   f.Demand();
}
catch(SecurityException)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You don't have access");
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
f.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, fullpath);
if (!SecurityManager.IsGranted(f))
    MessageBox.Show("You don't have access");
```

Both examples are didn't work for me. I am passing these steps although don't have any permission. Am I missing something?

I don't understand which one is the common way to check file permission? Actually, I don't want use **catch**  to handle like in Example 1.

By the way, Should I check the folder directory or full path to the file?

```
\\172.28.XXX.XX\\C:\\Files OR
\\172.28.XXX.XX\\C:\\Files\\abc.txt
```

Comment: I've found out that File.Exists(directory) returns false if you don't have any permission

Comment: Since File.Exists() isn't designed for that purpose, you should be careful. Furthermore this way you ain't able to distinguish, if a file doesn't exist or is just not accessible by the user. The recommended way by MSDN is indeed via FileIOPermission, as in example 2 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx